# WPF App MediaElement wont play sound

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

1. I have tried playing a `SystemSound.Beep` and it did play, so its not an issue with sound.
2. I tried all the solutions I could find but none worked.

My Code:

```
BG = new MediaElement();  // ... MediaElement BG; ...
BG.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
Grid.Children.Add(BG);
BG.Volume = 1;

BG.Source = new Uri("C:/Users/KUBA/Desktop/music/flying with rainbow dash.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);

BG.Play();
```

I also tried playing it after a second after the app was initialized, but didnt do anything.

Edit:
Turns out its a weird compatibility issue.
I decided to use Ffmpeg and SoundPlayer instead.

Edit 2:
Turns out SoundPlayer cant set time, so NAudio it is.

Comment: After further inspection, the media Position is always "00:00:00"

Comment: the Xaml Element generated by XamlWriter is:
'<MediaElement Source="C:/Users/KUBA/Desktop/music/flying with rainbow dash.mp3" Volume="1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Position="00:00:00" SpeedRatio="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />'

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. I just created a sample application with the same. One unknown is where BG is instantiated and how it might be manipulated after your code snippet. 

I declared mine locally in an anonymous delegate assigned to the `Loaded` event, so nothing else is messing with it.

Also have you tried it with another MP3 and in other locations?

Comment: @AnthonyT. I tried other files and locations, no change. I didnt do anthing with it after the snippet. I tried calling it from `MainWindow` and `MainWindow_Loaded`, neither worked.

Comment: Add a handler before you set the force for the MediaFailed event. Add some logging or display bits in there and see if the media player is getting an error.

Comment: @AnthonyT. OK, turns out, I dont have windows media player and cant download it because it isnt compatible with win10 64bit.

Comment: I decided to use SoundPlayer with conjunction with FFmpeg, but thanks for help!

Comment: Not familiar with the requirements of WMP, but I have WMP and I'm on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.